# How to prevent DateField record addition for past days in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

If I have a DateField() field in a model in Django, how can I prevent adding entries for dates older than today?

I can do it on the views.py level, but it would still be exploitable from the Django admin site.

To make matters worse, I have a design decision to have separate DateField() and TimeField() fields in the same model. Can I prevent addition into older (date+time) than the current time? It doesn't make sense to book a past flight, even if it was just an hour old. My problem, though, is that I have to have separate DateField() and TimeField(); not a single DateTimeField().

Comment: consider overriding the `save` method of the model.

Comment: As @karthikr said, overriding save() mehotd would take care of it, also if you gonna have some sort of datepicker widget with JS, you could only display the right dates on datepicker.

Comment: Are you allowed to _ever_ save a date in the past? i.e. for a past event, are you allowed to edit it's information but leave the date alone?

Comment: @karthikr Hello. If you could please elaborate with an example and put it in an answer, so I can try your solution and accept your answer!

Comment: @Thomas Sorry I don't understand what you're getting at, exactly.

Comment: @Voulnet If you overide save() on the model, it will prevent you from *ever* saving a model with a date in the past. So say you want to go back and modify an old record. You are then unable to save the modifications to that old record, even if you haven't changed the date, because the date is in the past.

Comment: @Thomas So what do you recommend in this case? Any other way I could prevent addition into the past from the admin page but without setting the constraint you mentioned (which is unacceptable as I might need to change non-date records in an old entry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try the `Model.clean()` method. This will raise `ValidationError`s in the right places (will show form errors in admin instead of 500).

The clean method will allow the expiry date to be saved in the past only if it is an existing record and the expiry has not changed.

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyModel(models.Model)

    expires = models.DateTimeField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__old_expires = self.expires

    def clean(self):
        " Make sure expiry time cannot be in the past "
        if (not self.id or self.__old_expires != self.expires)
           and self.expires <= datetime.now():
            raise ValidationError('MyModel entries cannot expire in the past.')
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: Would this raise an error if I wanted to modify and old record (to modify fields other than the date)?

Comment: It only checks that `seldf.expires <= datetime.now()` if it's a brand new record or if you have changed the values of the expires field. Hence you can safely modify the value of any other field of an old record.